# data retrieval vs modeling

Tags: probability, model

i don't have a specific mathematical setting for this question. it's rather high level.

if you have a bunch of data X for a variable that we want to predict Y, and all we care about is predicting within the range of observed values, is there utility in finding a model? why can't we just put a probability (distribution) for Y given some data X?

Comment: How are you going to find the probability distribution of Y given X? How does what you did / found differ from 'having a model'?

Comment: in some ways you can say that what i'm thinking *is* a model.
super simple example: P(Y=1 | X_{Y=1}={1,1,1,1,2})
80% Y will be 1.

Comment: Good point. In light of that, can you clarify your question?

Comment: aaah ignore my previous notation. it's wrong.

(X, Y)
(1, 1)
(1, 1)
(1, 1)
(1, 1)
(1, 0)

P(Y=1|X=1)=.8

i just don't see a need for modeling. i could have put this data in some regression.

correct? comments?

Comment: In making that estimate, you have *already* assumed a model: it appears to posit independent Bernoulli responses conditional on $X$. Moreover, you have actually gone further, because the formula for this estimate relies on information external to any probability model, such as a loss function, a prior distribution, or some quantitative expression of the objective. *E.g.*, in the same circumstances, with different assumptions, someone else might estimate $P(Y=1|X=1)=(4+1)/(5+2)=72\%$. So maybe the question ought to be, *what is the value in understanding the model you are using?*

Comment: ^ @whuber, i've been trying to bridge "common sense" (simple?) statistics with advanced statistical settings. your answer helped me here.

in this bridge is also, feature selection. in my example X was univariate of course. my motivating problem has many variables but i went ahead and assumed that only certain variables were predictive.